# how can i remove the login form from the home page

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to remove the login form from the front page, but i see both frontpage and user/login page are using the same template file: page--front.html.twig.

Is there a way to use two different template files for each page?

Comment: check your blocks, your login form might be a block.

Comment: Or your frontpage is set to /user. In that case, just configure the frontpage to whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Try going to `Admin/Structure/Blocks` and set `User account menu`'s region to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the front page set to null. I had to create an empty basic page and set it as front page to be able to have a front page different than the /user/login page. I don't feel it's the best way to do it, but it works.

Comment: use panels if you could try panopoly.

Comment: Panels is still in development for drupal 8. i wouldn't like to add a whole module for this...